# In java, is it possible to find the current objects on the memory heap at any particular point of time during execution?

Tags: java, memory, object

Say I have classes

```
class A{
  //code for class A
}


class B{
  //code for class B
}

class A{
  public static void main(String a[]){
    //Initialize m instances of A and n instances of B and store each in arrays
    //Equate any arbit index in the array to null
  }
}
```

In this scenario, my main goal is to find all active instances of classes A and B in the memory at any point.

I suppose it must be possible using a debugger.

However, due to some reason (the reason being beyond the scope of the question), I am required to get the instances from *within the code itself*. Thus, i need a function like

```
public void getAllActiveInstances(){
  //Print values
}
```

---

Edit: I don't need instances to operate over them. I just need to know whether they *exist or not*. This is mainly for debugging purposes. 
If this is not possible then  kindly explain how to do the same using debuggers.

Comment: "the reason being beyond the scope of the question" - then you're asking the wrong question. You shouldn't need to get the instances in the way you are trying.

Comment: @artbristol  +10.  'Asking the wrong question' is too often the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, you should not be looking inside of memory at any time with java.

The long answer is, if there was any way of accessing an object after GC has collected it, then you are violating the GC's principal of only collecting things that cannot be reached in any way by the executing code. Garbage collected memory is freed and returned to the program to do anything it wants with it. This means if you've GC'd an object A, java is allowed to write any number of things into that location, destroying the "A-ness" of that block of memory. Attempting to read an object B that is now stored in that memory block and pretending it's an A will cause all sorts of problems.

Going forward: To keep track of all the classes you've created, I would suggest modifying the class itself. Your class can have a `static` container (like a `HashMap`), and the constructor adds the constructed class to the `HashMap`. However, note that because you are hanging onto references to all of your created object, Garbage collect will never collect those objects and free up that memory.

Comment: That is exactly the trouble. If I use something like a HashMap, the GC can _never_ delete it. I basically want to make sure whether an object is deleted or not

Comment: You can't "make sure" GC deletes it. You shouldn't be worrying about Garbage Collect anyways, Java is designed so you don't have to worry about memory management on a day to day basis. Unless if you have a very good reason to, (and in that case, you should tell us what that is), you should just let GC do it's work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. By making sure, I mean I want to know if I haven't left any references to a particular object(the codebase is huge so I would prefer if I can avoid manual checking). If there are any references, GC wouldn't delete it. So I was wondering if it was possible to look at the Memory Map or something during runtime to make the task easier

Comment: You can do a reference counting paradigm for that then. In your class, you have a `int referenceCount;` It starts off as `0`, and for every time you grab the reference, say `myArray[2]=A;`, you also increment its reference count, and every time you lose the reference, say by doing `myArray[2] = B;` you decrement the reference count. You have to be really careful that way, though, but  you should be able to calculate the number of objects pointing to it by accessing the object's reference count.

Answer (score 1):

"In this scenario, my main goal is to find all active instances of classes A and B in the memory at any point irrespective of the Garbage Collector having deleted the object or not."

If the garbage collector has deleted it, it won't be an active instance, or indeed any kind of instance.

There is no Java API for this, sure JRockit Flight Control and/or a debugger could do this for you, but if you want an actual programmatic way of doing it, you'll have to hand-roll it. Good luck with making that reliable. You'll probably need to use Constructors and Finalizers to increase and decrease your object count.

Don't try and implement your own object pools unless you really, really think you can beat the hotspot optimiser at its own game.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you can do it using debugger. Java provides debugging API. You can kind of implement your own debugger and connect to the application itself.

Other way is to instrument your classes. I know the following techniques:

1. Instantiate them using special factory that stores references to all instances that have to be monitored.
2. Use AOP (e.g. AspectJ). The aspect will register created instances into repository (as described above)
3. Use [java instrumentation package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) to change class on the fly. Take a look on [SizeOf](http://sizeof.sourceforge.net/) - a very simple project that uses java instrumentation API. You can use it as an example to learn the issue.